# How to read JSON Object on the second array with Java/JavaFX code

Tags: java, json

I am trying to read JSON data with Java, I was successfully to read the first array, below is my JSON report from url.

```
{
  "success":1,
  "object":"sale",
  "id":"sl987575",
  "created":"2019-08-03 21:40:35",
  "product_id":"prd00123",
  "product_name":"AirBuss",
  "amount":"100.00",
  "currency":"USD",
  "status":"Completed",
  "meta":[],
  "customer":{
               "object":"customer",
               "id":"001234",
               "email":"someone@email.com",
               "name":"Full Name",
               "country":null,
               "firstname":"Full",
               "lastname":"Name"}}
```

I can read `"product_name"` and `"status"` but cannot read the `"email"` data.

```
    public static void call_me() throws Exception {
        String url = "Link WEbsite/api/?apiKey=23459876";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        // optional default is GET
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        //add request header
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        //print in String
        System.out.println(response.toString());
        //Read JSON response and print
        JSONObject myResponse = new JSONObject(response.toString());
        System.out.println("result after Reading JSON Response");
        System.out.println("Product Name : "+myResponse.getString("product_id"));
        System.out.println("status : "+myResponse.getString("status"));
        System.out.println("Email : "+myResponse.getString("email"));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your info @kleopatra I still learn Java and I am on high school..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found solution for my own question..

```
JSONObject customer_data = myResponse.getJSONObject("customer");
System.out.println("Email : "+customer_data.getString("email"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
System.out.println("Email : " + myResponse.getJSONObject("customer").getString("email"));
```

Because 'email', 'country' etc. fields in a nested object named **customer**.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @faranjit, but it's not worked still have an error, thank you

Comment: Hi @faranjit, I am sorry to late comment your question, I just re install my PC because there is error system and I lost all my code (I didn't backup the file) Now I am going to code again from scratch, anyway my code are same with previous question and just put a little code which you advice to me..